# Fixed size array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I'm developing a WPF game with C# and .NET Framework 4.5.1.

I have this class:

```
public class Player
{
    public Card[4] Hand { get; set; }
}
```

And I need to set that `Player.Hand` can only contain four cards (`Card` is a class that represent a card).

How can I do it? The above code show the exception `"matrix size cannot be specified in variable declaration"`. And if I use `List<Card>()`, I can set max size.

Comment: While the error is quite apparent here, posting the *actual* error is preferable to "It doesn't work". Just some advice for future questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The size of an array is *not* part of its type.

You need to *create* it with that size:

```
public Card[] Hand {get; set;}

public MyClass()
{
    Hand = new Card[4];
}
```

You could also use a full property and initialize the array to that size.

```
private Card[] hand = new Card[4];
public Card[] Hand
{
    get { return hand; }
    //Set if you want!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the property declaration, you should specify only property type, but not the data. The array size can be specified in the moment of array creation.

```
public class Player
{
   public void Initialize()
   {
       // An example of initialization logic
       Hand = new Card[4];
       for (int i = 0; i < Hand.Length; i++)
           Hand[i] = new Card();
   }

   public Card[] Hand { get; set; } 
}

public class Card
{
}
```